# Game centre leaderboards not updating - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, game-center

I have followed a tutorial on how to implement leaderboards into my ios game. However, when I put it on the app store, no one else's scores were appearing, just mine. I don't really know much about how game-centre works so I don't know where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TziN1O2x7pM

My code:

```
func authPlayer() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {
            self.viewController.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)
        }
    }
}

func saveHighscore(number: Int) {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated == true {
        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "wizard_leaderboard")
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)
        let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.report(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func showLeaderboard() {
    let viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()

    gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self

    viewController?.present(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```